# Модификаторы доступа в Java

Tags: java

Чем отличаются эти два класса, и какого типа будет класс во втором случае?

```
public class Man {
    int age;
    string name;
    Man (int age, string name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

и

```
class Man {
    int age;
    string name;
    public Man (int age, string name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть, по умолчанию - доступ из пакета (т.е. из этого пакета доступен, с другого нет).

Public доступен из любого другого класса. Если по нормальному всё делать, то в .java файле ровно 1 public класс и название файла совпадает с названием класса.

Comment: Понял,  спасибо.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html - по моему тут есть прекрасная табличка показывающая права.